# NetworkManager won't let me change my network settings, how can I do it (using NM)?

Tags: permissions, networkmanager

I use NetworkManager and I experience what apparently is a non deterministic behavior with respect to what I'm permitted to do, in particular sometimes I can switch the wireless and the networking, sometimes I can't; sometimes I can edit the parameter of the connections, sometimes I can't.

These changes, as far as I can tell, happen outside of a single session and I suspect that they are associated with working with a rolling release (Debian Sid) and changing often configuration files for all the involved packages.

That said, sadly it's a relatively long period that I can't...

I'm interested in actively change what NetworkManager lets me do because at work I'm supposed to use a script that talks to the NetworkManager over DBus to connect to the wireless, and the script fails to modify my settings.

Comment: Is it possible to post the NetworkManager relevant portions of the remote configuration script?

Comment: Oops, the _remote configuration script_? could someone please tell me the path name of the remote configuration script?

Comment: I meant the script that you are using to configure NetworkManager over DBUS.